# Open div on mouse enter and keep it open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make a `div` open when you hover a link. Which is simple enough and I'm doing fine. But I also want to be able to access the `div` without it closing. So if I hover over the newly opened div it will stay open. But If I hover out of the div I want it to close.

I also want to make sure that if I hover out of the link that the div closes. I have done this a few times before but for the life of me I cant sort it back out. I remember using `setTimeout` previously but my mind has went to mush and it's late so thought I might as well ask for some help.

I'm also aware that `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` would be far better than hover in this situation I just typed it up as hover for speed.

**UPDATE**
Changing the HTML is not an option this is a jquery question not an html or CSS one.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $("li.true a").hover(
    function() {
      $(".open").fadeIn(1000);
    }, function() {
      $(".open").fadeOut(1000);
    }
  );

  $(".open").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).show();
    }, function() {
      $(this).fadeOut(1000);
    }
  );

});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
li.true a {
  background-color: green;
}
li.true a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: green;
}
div.open {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>not</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>not</a>
    </li>
    <li class="true"><a>true</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>not</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>not</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="open"></div>
```

Comment: Why not use CSS :hover for this? It's a pretty good idea to use CSS over JS whenever possible.

Comment: Cant use CSS for this at all as its not a direct sibling and is outside the container of the activator

Comment: Don't Vote down because of criticism of a bad answer.

Comment: "But If I hover out of the div I want it to close." If you hover over fading div should it reappear?

Comment: that would cause it to open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this js it uses timeout

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 "use strict"; 
 var t;
 $("li.true a, .open").hover( function() { 
    clearTimeout (t);
   $(".open").fadeIn(1000); 
 }, function() { 
     clearTimeout (t);
    t = setTimeout(function(){
      $(".open").fadeOut(1000); 
    },1000);
 } ); 
});
```

Comment: Ill take this as the answer for now

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is not to use both parameters of hover in jquery. 
when hover on "li.true a" simply ignore the second parameter, which hides your div. use null to skip on div.open's hover.

<strike>but if you ask for the right way. use CSS for these type of interactions. there is no need for JS to do this.</strike>

Edit: If you need to hide it when on siblings of "li.true a"'s hover.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $("li.true a").hover(
    function() {
      $(".open").fadeIn(1000);
    }
  );
  $("li:not(.true) a").hover(
    function() {
      $(".open").fadeOut(1000);
    }
  );

  $(".open").hover(null, function() {
      $(this).fadeOut(1000);
    }
  );

});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
li.true a {
  background-color: green;
}
li.true a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: green;
}
div.open {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>not</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>not</a>
    </li>
    <li class="true"><a>true</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>not</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>not</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<div class="open"></div>
```

Comment: This only part solves the problem. as the div stays open unless you enter it.

Comment: Still densest solve as now you have the issue if you don't hover a link the div stays open

Comment: When do you want "div.open" to be hidden?

Comment: As Described in the Question if you hover out of the div or out of the activator link then it should close.

Comment: well. there is no such solution in my limited JQuery & DOM knowledge :)

Answer (score 2):

Move the `div` with the class `open` to the `li` as child element. The JS is now also simpler for your case. You can find the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/ej5gkgat/.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a>not</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>not</a>
    </li>
    <li class="true">
        <a>true</a>
        <div class="open"></div>
    </li>
    <li><a>not</a>
    </li>
    <li><a>not</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

New CSS:

```
ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
}
li.true a {
  background-color: green;
}
li.true a:hover {
  background-color: blue;
  color: green;
}
div.open {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  display: none;
}
```

New JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $("li.true").hover(
    function() {
      $(".open").fadeIn(1000);
    }, function() {
      $(".open").fadeOut(1000);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: Changing the html is not a solution if it was just a matter of moving the html I would not need to use JS

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with only css:

```
            body{ font-family:sans-serif; }
            nav {
                background:blue;
                padding:12px;
            }

            ul {
                list-style:none;

            }
            ul li {
                display:inline-block;
                padding:6px;
                border:1px inset white;
                cursor:pointer;
                transition:all .5s;
                background:red;
            }

            ul li:hover {
                background:white;
                color:black;
            }
            ul ul {
                display:none;
            }
            ul li:hover > ul {
                display:inherit;
                position:absolute;
                top:68px;
                float:none;
            }
            ul ul li {
                display:inherit;
                float:none;
                position:relative;
                left:-47px;
            }
```

HTML:

```
<nav>
            <ul>
                <li> Example.com </li>
                <li> Languages 
                    <ul>
                        <li> HTML </li>
                        <li> CSS </li>
                        <li> Javascript </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li> Something
                    <ul>
                        <li> Something </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: This is not close to my original HTML sorry.

Comment: No, but it works very well, and it removes the need for endless piles of `id`s.

Comment: Yak there is no endless piles of ID's also this is a JQuery question editing the HTML or CSS will not be taken as a solution. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it without timeout (not a big fan of), but with fadeTo() and stop()

Opacity is used to check visibility and calculate estimate remaining fade time.
[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JungleZombie/Lx37u3rr/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

    var fadeout = 1000;
    var fadein = 800;

    $("li.true a").hover(function() {
        var opacity = $(".open").css("opacity");
        opacity = opacity && opacity < 0.8 ? opacity : 0;
        $(".open").stop(true).fadeTo(fadein*(1-opacity), 1);
    }, function() {
        var opacity = $(".open").css("opacity");
        if (opacity > 0) $(".open").fadeTo(fadeout, 0);
    });    

    $(".open").hover(function() {
        var opacity = $(this).css("opacity");
        if (opacity > 0) $(this).stop(true).fadeTo(fadein*(1-opacity), 1);
    }, function() {
        $(this).fadeTo(fadeout, 0);
    });   

});
```